# deploy java jar remotely during maven build

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration

I have a small maven project that build a java jar file. I added a plugin (maven-antrun-plugin) in order to start it during maven's build phase. This also works in the build server (Continuum) which is good.

Now I would also like to copy the artifact jar to another server. What is the best way for doing that? I saw that you can make maven execute bash script, would that be a good way?

thanks!

Comment: How do you want to copy it? SSH, FTP, other? Another idea is to deploy it to your remote Repository (Nexus, Archiva, Artifactory). But it depends on what you want to do with it...

Comment: Hello! I want to copy it to another server using SSH I think, and then run the jar-file on the remote server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your server and what options you have for uploading jars there. One of the options could be to use [Maven Wagon plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/), which supports [number of protocols](http://maven.apache.org/wagon/), including ssh, ftp, webdaw.

Comment: Thanks, I will check out Wagon.